# WPF Window flicker by swiching the ShowInTaskbar property

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some modal window objects, made visibly by`ShowDialog`. Everytime i open a dialog, i want to hide it's owner from the taskbar by switching the `ShowInTaskbar` property to false. No Problem so far. The Problem is that the Window where i've changed the `ShowInTaskbar` property is shown for a short time in white (not renders?). Can i prevent this ?

Comment: post your current code. I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: ShowInTaskbar from true to false courses white flicker on the window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ShowInTaskbar` as far as I know is caused by Windows underlying implementation (similar issues go back and beyond WPF).  And I've seen a range of issues with it.

I don't think there is a work around it. `Normally that's done on startup - what you do is a bit untypical in a way.`

> It seems to be implemented by creating another transparent window
>   which owns the current one.
>   That is coming from MS guy - [Comment from Rob Caplan](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowscompatibility/thread/b2bd50e0-8b38-46f7-b2dc-22b8db261831/)

...**which kind of explains the 'flickering'** you're experiencing (and not just you, that's easily repeatable).

and more issues...
[WPF BUG, Window not show when showintaskbar is set to false when display is turn off automatically](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/d39b0d2d-a3d3-45c0-bd6c-2ef4e587931f/)